# Adding element ID to navigation items in Grails Platform Core Navigation API

Tags: grails, functional-testing, grails-platform-core

Is it possible to add HTML attributes such as `id` or `class` to each menu item generated by the [Grails Platform Core Navigation API](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/guide/nav.html)?

Perhaps something similar to:

```
home(controller: 'home', action:'index', titleText:'Home', elementId: 'navHome')
```

I am writing some functional tests which use the generated links. However, the link text (and possibly the URLs) might change. Using an ID would make the tests easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The Navigation API provides the ability to add additional values via the `data` map and custom menu item rendering.

### Example:

#### Step 1

Add the `data` map to the menu item definition in `config/AppNavigation.groovy`.

```
home(controller: 'home', action:'index', titleText:'Home', data: [elementId: 'navHome'])
```

#### Step 2

Reference the `data` map using `item.data.*` in the GSP file.

```
<nav:primary scope="some scope" custom="true">
    <li>
        <p:callTag
            tag="g:link"
            attrs="${linkArgs + [class:active ? 'active' : ''] + [elementId:item.data.elementId]}"
        ><nav:title item="${item}"/></p:callTag>
   </li>
</nav:primary>
```

This will result in the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav primary">
    <li>
        <a href="/VVAdmin/" id="navHome" class="active">Home</a>
    </li>               
</ul>
```

See the [nav:menu](http://grailsrocks.github.io/grails-platform-core/ref/Navigation%20Tags/menu.html) tag documentation in the Navigation API documentation for more information.